# Python script to get HTML source code from a list of URLs, is there a way to make this faster? Perhaps using Threadpool?

Tags: python, multithreading, html-parsing, threadpool, urllib2

For my internship, I have to parse a list of domains to get HTML source code and then figure out if a target string (var target) is in the HTML.

I'm writing a Python script. So far I have:

```
domains = open("domains.txt").readlines()
urls = ['http://' + domain[:-1] for domain in domains]

matches = 0
timeouts = 0

for url in urls:

    try:
        usock = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout = 1)
        data = usock.read()
        usock.close()

        if target in data:
            matches += 1

    except:
        timeouts += 1
```

The code is working in terms of finding matches where there should be matches, but it is running super slowly since I have to run this on huge clusters of thousands of domains, and the real time sink is in waiting for the URL result. I read in other threads that using multithreading specifically ThreadPool could save time, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing that here. Could someone please help me make this faster?

Comment: I'd take a look to [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests) to launch and process all the GET HTTP requests in parallel (unless you are adamant to doing it yourself with `urllib2` and threading tools)

Comment: Cool I had never considered grequests. I'm open to anything that will reduce the compute time xD

Comment: :-) Yeah, since you said it's for your internship, and therefore, is not an exercise _for learning purposes_, I'd go with pre-built libraries that handle the multiprocessing for you.

Comment: Is there documentation on how to do try/except with grequests?

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Comment: It looks like the support for exception handling (which was passed using `map(exception_handler=`) has been removed from the latest `grequests` (0.2.0) ? It looks like now every exception is catch and what happens is that  you get a `request` without an object! **:-S**

Answer (score 1):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import requests

def f(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(3)
    urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "http://www.youtube.com"]
    sources = p.map(f, urls)
```

Here's a sample using multiprocessing

Comment: If my list of urls is length > 1000, how do I need to setup the pool workers?

Comment: You just set the number of processors you want to use. And the they will continue grabbing from the list until they have finished all if them. And finally join into sources. So in the above example of the list of URLs were 1000 URLs. They'll work on it 3 at a time, or rather each on will work on one, then immediately grab the next one once it's done.

Comment: Is there a tradeoff in terms of increasing workers? As in would 10 be better than using 3 in this case?

Comment: It all depends on the resources your machine has, but multiprocessing is usually better then multithreading, as threading does functions back to back really quickly, and multiprocessing actually does it at the same time.